# How to create a left/right border with triangular shape instead of trapezoidal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a label with triangular shape in left and right, but I can only create trapezoidal shape:

```css
.borderLeft{
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-right:0.5em solid orange;
  border-top:0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:0.5em solid transparent;
}
.borderRight{
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-left:0.5em solid orange;
  border-top:0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:0.5em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="borderLeft"/>
    <td style="background-color:orange;">abcde</td>
    <td class="borderRight"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

is there any way to change the border at 2 sides from trapezoidal to triangular shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use after and before selectors to do that.

check this answer:

```css
.main {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  /* to vertical align text */
}

.main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.main:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">ABCDE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

0.5em is no enough to creat a triangular shape.Becoues td's height is 2em.

```css
.borderLeft{
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-right:0.5em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
}
.borderRight{
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-left:0.5em solid orange;
  border-top:1em solid transparent;
  border-bottom:1em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="borderLeft"/>
    <td style="background-color:orange;">abcde</td>
    <td class="borderRight"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.borderLeft {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-right: 0.5em solid orange;
  border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
}

.borderRight {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-left: 0.5em solid orange;
  border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" style="font-size:50px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="borderLeft" />
    <td style="background-color:orange;line-height:0">abcde</td>
    <td class="borderRight" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

You just need to set `line-height` to 0 for the 2nd td. Move the CSS to the CSS file instead of inline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `linear-gradient` and you can achieve this with one element and it will be responsive:

```css
.box {
  padding:10px 40px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to top right,orange 50%,transparent 50.5%) top right/40px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,orange 50%,transparent 50.5%) bottom right/40px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,orange 50%,transparent 50.5%) bottom left/40px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to top left,orange 50%,transparent 50.5%) top left/40px 50%,
   linear-gradient(orange,orange) center/calc(100% - 80px) 100%;
   
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">some text</div>
<div class="box">loooooooooooooooog text</div>
<div class="box">two line <br> text</div>
<div class="box">three<br> line <br> text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do a CSS trick pointed at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/. This is an example with label (you can change margin and font sizes to match your text)

```css
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  
  border-bottom: 80px solid orange;
}
.arrow-up > div {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:30px;
 margin-left:-30px;
 font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-up"><div >test</div></div>
```