# How to make hexagon in css elongated

Tags: html, css

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422524/css-responsive-elongated-hexagon-with-text-and-gradient-background-border) answer but I am using the following code from [here](http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/perfect-css-hexagons-size-using-transform-calc/) to make the hexagon. While the hexagon is responsive but am not being able to make it elongated. I am not much preferable with using the border solution and would like to go with adding classes to override existing styles.

```css
.socialIcon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: black;
    transition: color 400ms ease-in;
}
.color {
    background-color: #1ae694;
    transition: background-color 500ms ease-in;
}
.hexagonWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px;
}
.iconContainer {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.hexagon {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% * 0.57735);
    display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
    background-color: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    content: "";
    transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
.hexagon:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
    background-color: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    content: "";
    transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="socialIcon hexagonWrapper" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="color hexagon"></div>
  <div class="iconContainer">
    <span>H</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

I propose you to use Temani's method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691853/how-to-create-a-left-right-border-with-triangular-shape-instead-of-trapezoidal/50698511#50698511).
It uses multiple `linear-gradient`s to create the background, and needs less elements in the HTML:

```css
.socialIcon {
  color: black;
  transition: color 400ms ease-in;
}

.color {
  --color: #1ae694;
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.hexagonWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hexagon {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: inline-block;

  background:
   linear-gradient(to top right,    var(--color) 49.5%, transparent 50.5%) top right    / 20px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--color) 49.5%, transparent 50.5%) bottom right / 20px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to bottom left,  var(--color) 49.5%, transparent 50.5%) bottom left  / 20px 50%,
   linear-gradient(to top left,     var(--color) 49.5%, transparent 50.5%) top left     / 20px 50%,
   linear-gradient(var(--color), var(--color)) center / calc(100% - 40px) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/* Added after comment */
.hexagon:hover {
  --color: #aae;
}
```

```html
<a class="socialIcon hexagonWrapper" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="color hexagon"><p>xxx</p></div>
</a>
```

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old answer**

As a *elongated hexagon* is no more an hexagon, I propose you a totally different way to achieve this, using:

- CSS variables for the `height` and the `color`,
- `border`s on the pseudo elements to create the "triangle" shapes.

Here is a snippet:

```css
.socialIcon {
  --color: #1ae694; /* CSS Variable */
  --h: 100px; /* CSS Variable */
  width: 100px;
  height: var(--h); /* Using CSS var */
  color: black;
  transition: color 200ms ease-in;
}

.socialIcon:hover {
  --color: #aae;
}

.color {
  background-color: var(--color); /* Using CSS var */
  transition: background-color 500ms ease-in;
}

.hexagonWrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}

.iconContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* TAKIT: I changed everything below */

.hexagon::before,
.hexagon::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  content: "";
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  /* border is full height but half width, to render a thin arrow shape
  This can be parameterized here: */
  border-width: calc(var(--h)/2) calc(var(--h)/4); /* Using CSS var */
  transition:
    border-left-color 500ms ease-in,
    border-right-color 500ms ease-in;
}

.hexagon::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  border-right-color: var(--color); /* Using CSS var */
}

.hexagon::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  border-left-color: var(--color); /* Using CSS var */
}
```

```html
<a class="socialIcon hexagonWrapper" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="color hexagon"></div>
  <div class="iconContainer">
    <span>H</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Using that solution, the only thing to be adjusted is the `var: --h` to get an actual hexagon or an elongated one…

Comment: why not some linear gradient for this ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691853/how-to-create-a-left-right-border-with-triangular-shape-instead-of-trapezoidal/50698511#50698511

Comment: Because I don't want to repeat the same and I wasn't able to close as duplicate since there is no upvoted or accepted answer in the other question ;)

Comment: @TakitIsy With your original solution, I found one issue and that is if I set both width and height to be same I don't get a proper hexagon. Its always, an elongated hexagon.

Comment: @Ayan I meant `var(--h)`, sorry. True, for a proper hexagon... we may calculate to input the correct value.

Comment: @TakitIsy is it possible to have both elongated and proper hexagon in one go? Actually in my use case, I need to have three proper hexagonal buttons and one elongated. They also need to have some hover effect as they are buttons.

Comment: I managed to get a visually correct regular hexagon but currently having trouble to manage hovering on the element to change background colour.

Comment: @Ayan The problem in the second snippet is due to your DOM structure. The `iconContainer` element is above the `hexagon`, so you can't hover the `hexagon`. Instead, I suggest you to use `:hover` on the `socialIcon` element. I'm updating my snippet.  ⋅⋅⋅ Note that in the first snippet, it's a lot easier.

Comment: I meant a lot easier to `:hover`, but… sadly, we can't transition on a `linear-gradient`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Don't you have any amazing workaround to transition on a gradient ?

Comment: @TakitIsy of course ;) what kind of transtion you want to achieve?

Comment: @TemaniAfif In my 1st snippet, the OP wants a `500ms ease-in` of the color on `:hover`. (You can see my 2nd snippet as a result)

Comment: Is there any way to do something like `transition: --color 500ms ease-in;` ? (As `--color` is a property like variable… It would be wonderful).

Comment: for fading animation the only way is to duplicate layer and play with opacity like this : https://jsfiddle.net/mcuf2rnw/5/

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. Really.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create an "expandable" hexagon is to just put one at each end of a container, and have the center colored the same. Here's an execution of that, you can give negative horizontal margins to the center text to tighten up the spacing if necessary. I also cleaned up the hexagon generation code a bit to make it more dynamic - if you change the width of the `.hexagon` element, everything else resizes with it.

```css
.color {
    background-color: #1ae694;
    transition: background-color 500ms ease-in;
}
.text-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: flex;
}
.text-content span {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.expandableHex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.hexagon {
  width: 80px;
}
.hexagon-inner {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 173%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.hexagon-inner:before, .hexagon-inner:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: center center;
    background-color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: "";
}
.hexagon-inner:before {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.hexagon-inner:after {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<!--<a class="socialIcon hexagonWrapper" href="#" target="_blank">
  <div class="color hexagon"><div class="hexagon-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="color hexagon"><div class="hexagon-inner"></div></div>
  <div class="iconContainer">
    <span>H</span>
  </div>
</a>-->

<div class="expandableHex">
 <div class="hexagon"><div class="color hexagon-inner"></div></div>
 <div class="color text-content"><span>I'm content</span></div>
 <div class="hexagon"><div class="color hexagon-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```